# List items with action buttons in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I'm trying to create a list in Android in which each item has one ore more action buttons, as it's shown here with the number 2:

[image]

Is there any predefined way or template to do this, or do I have to manually create the views for the items in the list with their separators, action buttons and everything? (if that is the case, I would also appreciate some help with it :))

Thanks!

Comment: There is the [TwoLineListItem](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TwoLineListItem.html) which is nothing more than a large-font TextView above a small-font TextView, but this doesn't include an image. What have you tried?

Comment: I haven't really tried anything yet, I was looking for options before actually implementing anything. I didn't know about TwoListLineItem (thanks!) but I'm afraid that for now I need something more customizable, with buttons/images/etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to create your own layout for the rows. (You shouldn't need to do the separators.)

I do this in one of my apps. Here's one of the layouts I use for my items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescription_itemIcon"
        android:src="@drawable/album_placeholder" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/playButton"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/queueButton"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/playButton"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mainText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/queueButton"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:text="@string/placeholder_mainText" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rightAdditionalText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/leftAdditionalText"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/queueButton"
        android:text="@string/placeholder_rightText" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/leftAdditionalText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/mainText"
        android:layout_below="@id/mainText"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/rightAdditionalText"
        android:text="@string/placeholder_leftText" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's the adapter I use:

```
private class ItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<T> {
    private int rowLayoutId;

    public ItemAdapter(Context context, int rowLayoutId, T[] items) {
        super(context, 0, items);
        this.rowLayoutId = rowLayoutId;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(rowLayoutId, null);
            v.findViewById(R.id.queueButton).setOnClickListener(onQueueButtonClicked);
            v.findViewById(R.id.playButton).setOnClickListener(onPlayButtonClicked);
        }

        T item = getItem(position);
        if (item != null) {
            setText(v, R.id.mainText, item.name);
            fillRowView(v, item);
        }
        v.setTag(item);
        return v;
    }
}
```

Mine is parameterized with the row layout id for all items, but you may want to do that differently. The setText() and fillRowView() functions are helpers defined in the containing class.

Note that I set the item object into the row view's tag, so I can get it later in the button click handler:

```
View.OnClickListener onPlayButtonClicked = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View button) {
        View listItem = (View)button.getParent();
        Object tag = listItem.getTag();
        try {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            T item = (T)tag;
            // do someting with item
        }
        catch (ClassCastException e) {
        }
    }
};
```

You can see what this looks like [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rarepebble.musicplayer)

Comment: Wow, THANKS!! It seems that it's exactly what I was looking for, I'll give it a try and tell you how it went (and also check out your app, it looks great!).

And, for the record, I want to use this in my app Profile Widget ([link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cygnus.profilewidget)) :)

Comment: Hmmmm... is it too much if I ask you for the styles file? Of course I don't intend to literally copy all your layout, but it would be really helpful as a starting point (together with what you've already sent me) to create my own :) Thanks!

Comment: My styles.xml is a bit large and tangled, so not good for posting whole or extracting what's needed. Instead I've updated the layout above to need no styles.